# How to Scrape the IDs and Text relevant to IDs under heading?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**My Problem:**

I'm trying to extract text from multiple URLs on drugs.com. I can get the table of contents, but I have an issue obtaining the text under the table of content labels.

These two URLs have different navigational structures, so I'm having problems extracting only the content under a specific label

- https://www.drugs.com/pro/abacavir-and-lamivudine-tablets.html
- https://www.drugs.com/cons/a-b-otic.html

I need some help in understating how to extracting the content correctly for both URLs.

Here is my current code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

df = []
for i in ['https://www.drugs.com/cons/a-b-otic.html','https://www.drugs.com/pro/abacavir-and-lamivudine-tablets.html']:
    print(i)
    response2 = requests.get(i)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(response2.text, 'html.parser')
    data2 = soup2.findAll('ul', attrs={'class':'ddc-anchor-links'})
    print(data2)
    if len(data2)==0:
       data2 = soup2.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'ddc-toc-content'})
        empty = []
        for div2 in data2:
            link2 = div2.findAll('a')
            for c in link2:
                print(f"{c['href']} -- {c.text.lower()}")
                empty.append(c['href'].replace('#',''))
            print(f"{empty}")

        empty.append('moreResources')

        aa = {}
        for i in range(len(empty)):
    
            if i < len(empty)-1:
                s1 = str(soup2).find(f'id="{empty[i]}"')
                s2 = str(soup2).find(f'id="{empty[i+1]}"')
                s3 = str(soup2)[s1:s2]
                if 'uses' in empty:
                    s3 = "<h2 " + s3
                else:
                    s3= '<a ' + s3 
                aa[empty[i]] = s3
       df.append(aa)
    
    df11 = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

**My Output:**
[image: My Output]

**Desired Output:**
[image: Desired Output]

Comment: I would dump using these pages if possible and go with something that provides a nice API. Maybe something more formal like FDA?

Comment: @QHarr I didn't get it

Comment: Unless you absolutely have to use the website you show, which doesn't have a standard layout and risks you spending a lot of time building something which potentially frequently breaks, instead look for an alternative source that provides a more consistent format for data e.g. an API.

Comment: @Flameling Here is the link to the [FDA DRUG API](https://open.fda.gov/apis/drug/ndc/) that was mentioned above.